# Asynchronous script execution PHP

Tags: php, asynchronous

I need to execute a PHP script without blocking user interface.

Look this (light) example :

```
<?php
   echo "user see this";
   header("Location:otherpage.php");

        sleep(10);
        for($i=1; $i < 100000; $i++){
            $t = fopen("test.txt", "a+");
            fwrite($t, "$i\r\n");
            fclose($t);
        }
?>
```

This example need too much time to been executed, how to make it asynchronous and redirect the user witout interface waiting ???

Comment: Why don't you use jquery / ajax for that?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? There are multiple ways to solve this problem

Comment: I need to wrote something in database (position:wait), relocate to another page who show wait process, test with ajax if process ok, if ok, wrote in database success instead of wait, and replace wait with success in user interface.

Comment: Do you have access to the PCNTL functions like `pcntl_fork()` or to `system()/exec()/proc_open()` ?

Comment: Here's an example without using the above mentioned functions: http://php.net/manual/de/features.connection-handling.php#93441 .

Comment: Yes, it's my personal server ! With this type of command, can I access to the $_SESSION of user launch the background proccess ???

Comment: If you are able to send the php session id towards the new process, then yes you can resume a particular session

Answer (score 0):

I found a script who made what I need, but I don't understand it :

```
    ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);

$strURL = "PUT YOUR REDIRCT HERE";
header("Location: $strURL", true);
header("Connection: close", true);
header("Content-Encoding: none\r\n");
header("Content-Length: 0", true);

flush();
ob_flush();

session_write_close();

// Continue processing...

sleep(100);
exit;
```

Someone can explain ?

Comment: When using the default `session handler` from PHP, session are stored in a file, thus creating a file lock when a request is being handled. By closing the session with `session_write_lock`, you close the filelock and you are able to start a 2nd request without to have to wait on the first to complete

Comment: Is this a nice issue ?

Comment: @Azee You received a downvote because you should create a new question rather than asking a new question in an answer. Nevertheless here an explanation: https://pastebin.com/KAVWbxmJ .